# WP7 page background image

Tags: windows-phone-7

I plan to use a background image for each of my pages in WP7 and not keep the background transparent.
Any suggestions or issues I need to be aware of?

Also, I noticed a `CacheMode` property.
Can I use that to improve performance if each of the pages will have the same background stretching across the entire page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an Image control sized to full the display and lay your other controls in front of it.

If there is a reason you expect this control to be redrawn, then bitmap caching will save you the overhead of rasterising the control repeatedly.

Comment: Mick, thanks.  You are always available to help. I am using an imagebrush on the page's main grid to display the entire background.  Should I use the CacheMode property to set the bitmap caching? Will the background get cached for all the pages then or it will still get loaded for each page. Maybe the last part doesn't apply but I am coming from ASP.NET world :)

Comment: @Pratik I don't think separate pages share resources/backgrounds if you define them at the page level - you might be able to point the page backgrounds to an imagebrush defined at the Application level if you're super worried about performance, but to be honest unless you're using enormous images, I wouldn't be too worried about it. As a sidenote, WP7 seems loves caching anything you download (which you will discover if you have a play with System.Net.WebClient on the phone)

Comment: Blakomen is correct in that each page will have it's own background. Bitmap caching I would only worry about if you are doing redraws. Keep in mind bitmap cache means as the control (in your case grid with an imagebrush applied to background) is drawn, the rasterised (bitmap), rendition of this control is kept in memory. That is all.. it is not caching the file system where you read the source image from.

Comment: Thanks Blakomen and Mick.  So, if I have a page with a grid whose background is set to an ImageBrush that displays a page height image and I have another listbox inside this grid which has 20 different small product images inside it - I should enable CacheMode on the listbox, or each small product image or on the main Layout Grid itself.

Answer (score 7):

2 steps:
(1)
in
 **`<phone:PhoneApplicationPage`** 
set    **shell:SystemTray.IsVisible = "False"**

---

(2)

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
<Grid.Background>
<ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/Images/Flowers.png"></ImageBrush>
</Grid.Background>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put it on the PhoneApplicationFrame instead of puttin it on each page: it will then load only once and for all...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of performance issues you should be aware of:

1) Ensure large images are compiled as `Content` and not `Resources`.  Compiling as `Resource` will build the image into the binary executable itself, which makes it much larger to load in to memory on startup.

Jeff Wilcox:

> If you’re using Panorama, a Resource
>   background will load immediately
>   compared to Content

2) Unless you really need transparency use .jpg files rather than .png.  The .jpg decoding algorithm is significantly faster than .png. However beware of compression.  What is a tiny image on disk consume much more memory once it has been decompressed in memory.